I'd like to swap this item with another if one is available
Does "one" here mean the number or refering to the item?

Edit
Here one means another piece with the same attributes as this item.
We may add more descriptions for flexibility:
I'd like to swap this item with another if a similar one is available.
I'd like to swap this item with another if one with a similar design (or 'size') is available.

The entry in the Cambridge Dictionary shows the pronoun meaning https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one

I think it refers to both the item and to the number one.
The Item

I'd like to swap this item with another if one is available.

One means another item that's the same as this item. For example, a shorter version of your example is:

I'd like to swap this item with another one.

The Number (I inserted a comma below for emphasis)

I'd like to swap this item with another, if one is available.

It also means the number one, if 1 is available.
Let's say you had two items to swap. You might say:

I'd like to swap these two items, if two are available.

Here it means both two similar items as well as the number 2. The implication is that if you only have one item to swap, that won't meet my needs.
